# How can I detect when the swift application is foreground from the background?

Tags: swift, observable, lifecycle

I want to run a function in my application if the application is not running from the background. How can I do that?

I cannot use applicationDidBecomeActive and applicationDidEnterBackground because I need to detect the situation when it comes from the background, not the state when it is being taken to the background or when it is opened.
Also, when the application is opened for the first time, it will not work when it comes from the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need [willEnterForegroundNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622944-willenterforegroundnotification).

> Posted shortly before an app leaves the background state on its way to
> becoming the active app.

Keep in mind thow that this notification posted olso after `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` when opening the application for the first time.

When application opens for the first time the `applicationState` is [inactive](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationstate/uiapplicationstateinactive?language=objc) and when the application comes from the background the `applicationState` is [background](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationstate/uiapplicationstatebackground?language=objc).

So, your code will be something like this:

```
token = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    forName: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification,
    object: nil,
    queue: .main
) { (notification: Notification) in
    if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .background {
        // Came from the background
    }
}
```

Comment: With this method, can we not distinguish between the first time the application was opened and the background? @gcharita

Comment: Thank you very much Did it into the app delegate. should i write

Comment: Just be aware that if you use this in say a view controller, it's impossible for the state to be "inactive"; view controllers are not brought up until much later.

Answer (score 5):

#### Check the current state:

Use `UIApplication.shared.applicationState`.

```
switch UIApplication.shared.applicationState {
case .active: // The app is running in the foreground and currently receiving events.
case .inactive: // The app is running in the foreground but is not receiving events. This might happen as a result of an interruption or because the app is transitioning to or from the background.
case .background: // The app is running in the background.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
            .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newPhase in
                if newPhase == .active {
                    print("Active")
                } else if newPhase == .inactive {
                    print("Inactive")
                } else if newPhase == .background {
                    print("Background")
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct solution in SwiftUI